# Unknown column 'david' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

```
String username = "dav2018";
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Utilisateur WHERE login = "+ username;
```

Comment: Please add some description about your problem.

Comment: more detail please. Like the actual script. What you mean to accomplish and what you're using. You doing this right in mysql? In js? In c#? etc

Comment: when i execute this requet , i got this eror : Unknown column 'dav2018' in 'where clause'

Comment: You should NEVER build queries with string concatenation. Especially if you use values provided by the user. That's opening your code for SQL injections. Use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add single quotes around the value(`login='username'`). Try,

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Utilisateur WHERE login = '" + username + "'";
```

---

String concatenation in queries open the path to SQL injections. Research on using `PreparedStatement`s instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String username = "dav2018";

String sql = "SELECT * FROM Utilisateur WHERE login ='"+ username +"'";
```

But the solution above is vulnerable to Sql injection so instead of it you should use PreparedStatement as shown below :

```
String username = "dav2018";
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Utilisateur WHERE login =?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1,username);
```